# Light Switch Wiring, hot wire to lights

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a light switch that has the black wire attached to the bottom terminal and the white wire attached to the top terminal. Is there any way I can add another light switch for recessed lights to this circuit?

Comment: Please add some more detail to the question.  Do you have recessed lights now?  What does this switch control?

Comment: 1. The way you describe the wiring sounds weird. It SHOULD be that the hot wire (black) goes to the switch, then other black from switch to light, and the white wires tied together.

2. Do you mean add another light to the switch, or make it a three way switch?

Comment: @Ben it's a **switch loop**.

Comment: @Harper
Is it common to be set up that way?
I understand what you are saying, but I would hope that people don't generally do it that way.

Comment: @Ben what do you mean?  You hope people don't use switch loops?  Use of a white as a hot wire was sorta outlawed in 2011 in that you must now bring neutral to the switch (and that must be on white), but the idea of bring power to the light and having the switch be a spur is still SOP.

Comment: Can you find the box for the lights/receptacle this switch controls?

Comment: @Harper, Do new installs use 14/3 for "switch loops" now to provide a neutral and switch with red and black?

Comment: If the jurisdiction has adopted NEC 2011 or local equivalent, yes @JPhi1618 ...

Comment: When the white wire is used in a switch loop like this, there should always be a piece of black electrical tape wrapped near the end of it so it's easily identified as such (particularly after the switch has been disconnected).

Answer (score 1):

The hot and neutral are at the light box. Another Romex is ran down to the switch box and viola, a switch loop.

You cannot use this for more lights unless you rewire some things and add more wiring to this switch.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a switch loop. What this means is the power for the lights is delivered to one of the lights and then this wire breaks the hot to turn the lights off, to add more lights using this circuit you would need to pull another line to that switch box and feed the new lights from the existing hot , neutral and ground. If you have attic access to the wiring it would not be two hard, without access you would need to open the walls / ceiling to run new wires. It can be done but is a lot more work for the second switch and new fixtures.